# Conexión falló: 1045 : Access denied for user

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero realizar una conexión a una base de datos externa a mi dominio, funcionaba hasta hace unos dias. Pero dejo de funcionar.
Mis datos de conexión son como el siguiente ejemplo:

```
define('DB_HOST', hostB);
define('DB_USER', admin);
define('DB_PASS', password);
define('DB_NAME', bd);
$con = ''; 
# conectare la base de datos
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
```

Me da como resultado Access denied for user 'admin'@'hostA' (using password: YES)
Mi dominio actual esta en el servidor hostA, por lo cual se me hace extraño que la solictud la realice al hostA y no al hostB como se indica en los datos de conexion. Espero me puedan ayudar

Trate de cambiar el host por la ip del dominio pero siguio dando el mismo resultado

Comment: ¿Dónde exactamente ves ese error? ¿Hay en el mensaje de error alguna referencia a una ruta de archivo? Puede que el error provenga de otro código, no del que nos muestras.

Comment: El error lo marca en la linea que realiza la conexion $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

Comment: ¿Verificaste que en el mensaje de error la ruta del archivo es **exactamente** la misma? Por otra parte, ¿por qué pones los valores sin comillas al definir las constantes?

Comment: sobre las comillas, en la pregunta se me paso agregarlas, en el codigo si las tengo.
Sobre la ruta es la misma que mi conexion que les muestro y me lo indica exactamente donde se realiza la consulta, ya agregue un try catch pero me sigue mostrando el mismo error donde se trata de conectar a desde el hostA

Comment: `try ... catch` no funciona en mysqli. No es posible que tengas definido `hostB` y que el mensaje de error hable de `hostB`. Una de dos: 1. O estas revisando en el lugar equivocado; 2. O se quedó en la caché un código viejo.

Comment: No se a que te refires con que no funciona en mysql, lo ejecute y lo no me marca algun error, en l catch toma la excepcion sin problema, pero en efecto estoy seguro que lo el proceso esta bien, no existe ningun otro codigo ya que pueda revisar. La cache igual ya la elimine si es que llego a tener. 
Este proceso ya lo realice hasta de forma local y no tengo problema con la conexion. Aun no le encuentro sentido

Comment: No te entiendo. Mysqli no tiene manejo de excepciones, por tanto try ... catch no funcionaría en ese caso. Como ya dije, si el mensaje de error muestra datos distintos de los que tienes en tu archivo, entonces el error está ocurriendo en otro archivo o bien tienes datos distintos debido a problemas de caché.